# FILTER function with checks on multiple columns and values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two sheets: one with raw data and one where I want to filter out only rows of interest.  In the raw data sheet, I have two columns that need to be filtered (say, Columns B and C).  Column B is only Yes/No. Cells in Column C have 26 unique values to choose from (say, "A" through "Z").

**Raw Data Example (Sheet 1):**

| Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name_1 | Yes | A | more data |
| Name_2 | No | D | more data |
| Name_3 | Yes | K | more data |
| Name_4 | Yes | G | more data |

**Filter Example (Sheet 2, desired):**

| Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name_1 | Yes | A | more data |
| Name_4 | Yes | G | more data |

In the example above, I want to filter out **only "Yes"s from Col B**, and **only {A, B, C, G, H, J} from Col C**.  How would I do this?

I tried something like:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!$A:$K, AND(Sheet1!$B:$B="Yes", ISNUMBER(MATCH(Sheet1!$G:$G,Lookup!$A$2:$A$7,0))), "No Rows Found")
```

where 'Lookup' is a sheet containing:

| Lookup Values |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| G |
| H |
| J |

I keep getting #VALUE!  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `AND()` function in `FILTER()` function, use the `*` operator which works as `AND()`

[image]

---

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:D5,(1-ISNA(XMATCH(Sheet1!C2:C5,LOOKUP!A2:A7)))*(Sheet1!B2:B5="Yes"))
```

---

And instead of using the whole range, use `Structured References` aka `Tables` to select only the desired range.

---

Or, If you are reluctant to use `Structured References` aka `Tables` then use the following to get the `_LastRow`, in the following formula I have assumed `Column A` will have a value and can be taken as index column for the `_LastRow`

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _LastRow, MATCH(2,1/(Sheet1!A:A<>"")),
     _Data, Sheet1!A2:INDEX(Sheet1!A:D,_LastRow,),
     _CriteriaOne, (INDEX(_Data,,2)="Yes"),
     _CriteriaTwo, 1-ISNA(XMATCH(INDEX(_Data,,3),LOOKUP)),
     FILTER(_Data,_CriteriaOne*_CriteriaTwo,"No Rows Found"))
```

---

- `_LastRow` --> Variable returns the last row of the data range using the `MATCH()` function.
- `_Data` --> Using the `_LastRow` variable extracting the whole data from `Sheet1` using `INDEX()`
- `_CriteriaOne` --> does a `Boolean` Logic check on column B to see whether it is `Yes` or not.
- `_CriteriaTwo` --> does an exact match with the `LOOKUP` Sheet to find the required matches.
- Finally, using `FILTER()` returning the output, after doing a `Boolean` operation to return `True` or `1` for all the matches. Else it would return `No Rows Found`

---

**Note:** `LOOKUP` refers to defined named range in `LOOKUP Sheet` --> `=LOOKUP!$A$2:$A$7` and here is an excel to **[download](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckmLVnieCsdRFXVAW?e=yLs6qd)**.

---

Comment: This is an incredible answer. Thank you! Could you explain how the `_LastRow, MATCH(2,1/(Sheet1!A:A<>""))` portion works? In particular, I don't understand what `1/(Sheet1!A:A<>"")` is doing. My naive understanding is that this segment returns an array of 1/TRUE (i.e., 1/1 = 1) and 1/FALSE (i.e., 1/0 = NaN).

Comment: @user12386 if you try to evaluate that part of the formula, then you will see it is showing `{1;1;1;1;1;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;etc}` so it is checking whether the range is blank or not, if its blank it returns an error because `1/0` is in mathematical terms is **∞** and hence it shows as `#DIV/0!` error. and finds the last `1` in the array by approximate match.

Comment: @user12386 is it working for you? is it solved?